# PhP name space on identical configurations

Tags: php, configuration, namespaces

I have an uncommon problem with my development machine.

She is the same we use on the production server, but for some reason when i run on my vm somthing like

```
namespace NotWorking;

$foo = new DateTime();
```

It works on my local machine but fails witout any error on our production server.

but when i use somthing like:

```
namespace Working;

$foo = new \DateTime();
```

it works. we compared already all settings known to me but did not find any diference in the build from php and even apatche is the same build.

Is there a option to enforse this "feature"?

Answer (score 2):

DateTime is in the global namespace, and as "class names always resolve to the current namespace name" you have to use \DateTime

You can read more about it [here](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php)

If you ever have a class in the local namespace with the same name as one in the global namespace, you have to prefix `\`, or you'll just be importing the local class.

Comment: The wierd thing is i dont have a class that is called like that. And that it works just fine on one machine but not on other one. Thy for the good reference point.

Comment: @Sangoku You should always be using backslash with all native PHP classes no matter on what machine You are. The case it is working well on Your local machine is kinda weird - but probably due to the current namespace being the same as the global namespace...

Comment: @shadyyx Well said Sangoku make sure u use '\' this is weird why it workks on your machine :)

Comment: Well I agrea that you should use like stated, but im not having this wierd bug just on one machine. Every dev. has his VM and we have a alpha machine which is for testing purposes. And it is like that on both. And it just can slip detection easill, and when you go live BOOOM!
Forgot to mention one more thing. Thouse machines are identicall in setup! same php version same ini same all... for testing purposes.